# Along/In The Greatest Dimension

Tags: meaning, prepositions, usage

Suppose the context is measuring a size of a piece of rock:

> 1. The rock measures 10 cm ***along*** the greatest dimension.
> 2. The rock measures 10 cm ***in*** the greatest dimension.

Should it be "*along*" or "*in*"?

Comment: I’d say either is acceptable, but I’d use [in/along] ***its*** greatest dimension.

Comment: "along" might imply "along an edge", but the object might be pointed (i.e. not close to rectangular), so the greatest dimension is a distance _through_ the object, rather than along an edge.  So I would favor "in its greatest dimension".  But I wouldn't say "along" is wrong—it's just that one has to think of measuring "along" an _invisible line_ passing through the object.

Comment: Also consider _"the rock measures 10 cm along its **major axis**"_

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that "**along**" sounds better to me although "**in**" might also be possible. I wouldn't say that the change from "**the**" to "**its**" isn't absolutely necessary but it does improve it.

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion the two choices I'd use would be "**along**" and "**across**" if speaking about an axis or a dimension.

- The tree measures 8 meters along/across its height.

Otherwise, I'd prefer:

- The height of the tree measures 8 meters.